# unable to retrieve data from Nodejs local server on devices on the network with react frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, next.js

My client app is on localhost:3001
My server app is on localhost:3000

server is listning on 0.0.0.0:3000

data load normally on my Mac but,

I am able to retrieve data on mobile devices on network only from localhost:3001 but not from localhost:3001/page

I am calling the exact same request no changes whatsoever

when i call it from /page i get network error from axios

the request call is like this

```
export const getRecentStores = async (page, limit) => {
  try {
    const params = {};
    if (page) params.page = page;
    if (limit) params.limit = limit;
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${parentPath}`, { params });
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

my server cors are like this

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: env === "development" ? "*" : "",
    methods: "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    allowedHeaders:
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, User-Agent, Authorization",
  })
);
```

listening on server like this

```
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`server is up and running at: enviroment: ${env}, PORT:${port}`);
});
```

not sure what is going wrong please help if you have knowledge in this regard.

error object:

[image: error]

Comment: What error you have exactly? Could you post it?

Comment: It is exactly only `Network Error.` and after research I could only see that it is most probably a a cors issue or some sort of an issue

Comment: So post the message of an error?

Comment: updated the question to show the error.

Comment: I had to take a screenshot as this only happens on mobile devices

Comment: The error seems to be complaining about a request to `/api/stores` in your `_app` file. Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: here is the thing, I am not calling any requests in `_app.js` here is a code snippet from `_app.js` 

https://codepen.io/raffi23-the-lessful/pen/MWmXgQr?editors=1010

Comment: i have been experimenting with this, i have created a middleware on the express app but it seems like the request is not even reaching the server, issue is happening whenever i call an async function in a `useEffect` but if i call the same request in `getStaticProps` no issues at all. i am not sure if this could be a help to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have not updated `axios` `baseUrl` to my machine IP address and I was using localhost which led to this problem on devices on local network.

The reason that request is working on index page is that I was fetching on `getStaticProps` which will already fetch data from my localhost on hosting device and send the html with populated data to my local devices.